# How to block parent without blocking child in ublock

Tags: adblock

I want to be able to block everything on a page but a picture.

Example: https://imgur.com/gallery/wJIyDIF

```
@@||i.imgur.com/St95Jdv.jpg

imgur.com##.post-pad.left      < this overrides the previous line, order doesn't matter.
```

Ideally I would love something like this:

```
imgur.com##html

@@||i.imgur.com/St95Jdv.jpg
```

Or this:

```
imgur.com##html > body

@@||i.imgur.com/St95Jdv.jpg
```

But no idea how to actually make it work

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure, it is not possible. Every matching element is blocked *with its children*. Indeed, where would the children even be placed if their parent is hidden?

Your best hope is to block all *siblings* of the element you wish to keep...

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't be possible. I'm looking to do the same thing, with something of the form "block all elements other than X, if its parent is Y", which would block almost everything within the parent, without blocking the parent itself.

Comment: That's different from the asker's question. You're not seeking to block the _parent_ -- you're seeking to block some of its other children -- siblings of the element you want kept.

Comment: True, but in the case when the parent is just a container for its children, the end result is the same. My point is, the original asker's question is slightly different from their intent; what I'm asking is probably what the original asker should be asking as well. So it's similar to "block all siblings of X" like you said, but with the added conditional of "only do so to instances of X which are children of Y".